# Nested thread groups

Tags: jmeter

There are 4 thread groups that run different tests simultaneously (mostly http requests). In one thread group I need to run two http requests at once. How to do it? JMeter is not allowing to nest thread groups.

Comment: You need 2 requests to execute in parallel?

Comment: Yes but these requests are already in a thread

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need to run 2 requests at once for the same thread (VIrtual User) , you need to use this plugin:

- https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-bzm-plugins/blob/master/parallel/Parallel.md

You can install it with [plugin manager.](https://jmeter-plugins.org/install/Install/)